# Evento blur en javascript ¿Como obtener datos con js ingresados en un input html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo el siguiente código en el que imprimo el campo observación de mi tabla evaluación

```
<td>
<input data-id_observa="<?php echo $evaluacion['id_evaluacion']; ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $evaluacion['observacion']; ?>" id="observa">
</td>
```

he colocado el input porque quiero que ese campo sea editable, ahora lo que yo quiero es que después de haber editado dicho campo y al hacer clic fuera de él esto se guarde automáticamente,
a través de JavaScript lo he logrado con el método **blur** pero lo que no me carga es el valor que ingresado en el input aquí les muestro mi código JS

```
$(document).on("blur", "#observa", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id_observa");
    //obtener el valor ingresado en el input
    var observa = $(this).text();

    alert(observa);
})
```

a ver si me pueden ayudar por favor, como puedo mostrar los datos ingresado en el input lo intente a través de **getElementById** pero solo me carga el valor de la primera fila cuando ingreso datos en otra fila y hago clic fuera me sigue apareciendo los datos ingresado en la primera fila.

Comment: ¿Existe sólo un elemento con atributo `id` igual a `observa`? Porque si hay más de uno ese es un problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que quedaría así, donde el input al perder el foco ejecutara la función que especifiques, en este caso los alert, ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".observa").on("blur", function() {
    //obtener el id ingresado en el input
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //obtener el valor ingresado en el input
    var observa = $(this).val();

    alert('El id del input en el que estabas es: ' + id);
    alert('El value del input en el que estabas es: ' + observa);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>

    <input id="5" class="form-control observa" type="text" value="Aun no hay valor PHP">

    <input id="2" class="form-control observa" type="text" value="Otro valor PHP">
  </body>

</html>
```

Si modificas el **value de los input** te mostrara el valor modificado en el **alert**.
Dime si te sirbio.

Comment: Excelente amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió muchísimo.